# UISplitViewController, animating views

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to animate my detail view controller to transition with a page curl (up/down). I'm trying to achieve a similar effect as the **Notes** application on the iPad, this transition was also reproduced by CulturedCode in their **Things** application for iPad.

My problem is that the animation is clipped to the bounds of the Detail View Controller, it doesn't animate into the Master View Controller, therefore limiting the effect. I see that Apple and CulturedCode managed to make this happen, but I'm stumped.

I've tried the following solutions:

self.splitViewController.view.clipToBounds = False;
self.view.clipToBounds = False;
self.tableView.clipToBounds = False;

The only other solution I can think of is discarding the UISplitViewController altogether and creating my own VC programmatically that will mimic the UISVC behavior so that both of the views (former separate view controllers) will share the same Super View.

Thank you in advance, any advice will help.

RR.

Answer (score 2):

A solution it to just set `clipsToBounds` to `NO` and bring the details view to the front in it's superview. Like so:

```
detailsView.clipsToBounds = NO;
[detailsView.superview bringSubviewToFront:detailsView];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:detailsView cache:YES];

...

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Where `detailsView` is your container for the details pane. This should do the trick and the details view will animate in front of the master view. I now have my page transition look quite like the Notes app.